# Check if String is HTML or not in ruby

Tags: ruby, string

How can we check the string is HTML or not  using Ruby?

If string contains html tag then returns true otherwise false

Comment: [Try to parse it and check if you failed](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/ensuring_well_formed_markup.html).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> If string contains html tag then returns true otherwise false

You can accomplish this test pretty simply:

```
def has_html_tag?(string)
  string =~ /<html.*?>/
end

has_html_tag?('<html lang="en">foo</html>') #=> true
has_html_tag?('12345') #=> false
```

However, this test is not sufficient to determine whether a string is a valid HTML document or a valid HTML fragment.

> How can we check the string is HTML or not using Ruby?

You can get some basic HTML validation from the Nokogiri gem:

```
$ gem install nokogiri

require 'nokogiri'

Nokogiri::HTML.parse("<foo>bar</foo>").errors.empty?
```

Comment: This will return true for a string that does not contain HTML tag.

Comment: @Espen I'm not sure I understand what you intend to communicate by saying this.

Comment: The question was whether the string contains HTML tag or not. Not whether HTML is invalid or not. Nokogiri::HTML.parse("foo bar").validate and Nokogiri::HTML.parse("<foo>bar</foo>").validate will both return true. Thus not sufficient to tell whether the string contains HTML tag or not.

Just wanted to clarify this as this answer was marked as best answer for this question.

Comment: @Espen It seems you have two things to say. Regarding 1. "this answer doesn't answer the question": The green check mark indicates that the original asker was satisfied with this answer, so perhaps you have misunderstood their question. Regarding 2. "`Nokogiri::HTML.parse("foo bar").validate` and `Nokogiri::HTML.parse("<foo>bar</foo>").validate` will both return true": No, they both return an array containing `Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError` objects, as I wrote above. An array is a `true`-ish object in Ruby, so using a logical test without examining the result may have led you to be mistaken.

Comment: Not sure why you are being so defensive here. It obviously isn't the correct answer to "If string contains html tag then returns true otherwise false". You are indeed correct that it returns an array and not true (I meant neither will give any error but that wasn't an accurate statement), however that is really irrelevant to the question so not sure why you elaborate on it instead of either admitting that this should not be marked as the correct answer or explain how the returned array can be used to answer the question. Not trying to pick a fight but kinda strange to defend this.

Comment: @Espen One can infer that because this answer has the approval of the asker that the first part of the post ("How can we check the string is HTML or not using Ruby?") was the real question, and the other non-question part ("If string contains html tag then returns true otherwise false") is their first guess at how one might accomplish the task—an approach which everyone who has posted an answer here has improved upon (by not using it). If you're unsatisfied with the state of this question and its answers, the right thing to do might be to edit that confusing sentence out of the original post.

Comment: @Espen Reflecting on this question/answer more, I definitely see what you mean. The question is rather ill-defined, and I don't think there's a good way to answer it without knowing what the real goal was. I've updated my answer so that folks who approached it the same way as you did also get something useful.

Answer (score 6):

If you just want to see if a fragment of html is correct without validating tags:

```
Nokogiri::XML("<foo>bar</foo>").errors.empty?
```

Answer (score 3):

One way to check if your text has HTML in it is with [`strip_tags`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-strip_tags) (if you're using Rails):

```
def has_html?(text)
  strip_tags(text) != text
end
```

This will tell you if there are HTML tags in the text, regardless of whether it's valid or not.

Comment: Heads up: this method can cause false positives, because `strip_tags` applies HTML-encoding to _all_ strings, regardless of whether they are HTML.  Eg: `puts strip_tags('&') ==> '&amp;'`;.  Similarly `has_html('https://foo.bar?x=1&y=2') ==> true`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very broad question. First of all, do you want to validate the semantic or the syntax of HTML?

Validating the format may be easy, but it doesn't mean that a valid HTML document contains semantically valid tags.

```
<foo>bar</foo>
```

is a syntactically correct HTML document, however it's not semantically valid.

The most simple way to proceed is to [try to parse the document](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/parsing_an_html_xml_document.html) and rescue the exception. If Nokogiri raises the exception, then the document is not valid HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Let us say that the string we want to check is

```
test_string = "<ul>\n\t<li>item 1</li>\n\t<li>item 2</li>\n</ul>"
```

If you want to check if the entire HTML is correct or not. This will throw an exception even if a tag of the higher hierarchy is missing.

```
Nokogiri::HTML.parse(test_string).errors.empty?
#return false
```

If you are looking to check for a fragment you should go with

```
Nokogiri::XML.parse(test_string).errors.empty?
#return true
```